# only one companion object is allowed per class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, static-methods

I was switching from Java to kotlin for Android Devlopment. When I searched about equivalent of Java static methods in Kotlin, I found that companion object is. But the problem is while creating more than one static methods in kotlin. I get these errors only one companion object is allowed per class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put multiple methods and properties inside an [object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations). They're just like classes, but they have a single instance.

```
class A {
    companion object {
        fun a() {}
        fun b() {}

        val x = 42
        var y = "foo"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can set it as

```
class C {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun foo() {}
        fun bar() {}
    }
}
```

### See this [link for static method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods)

Comment: what's @JvmStatic for?

Comment: quoting from docs `If you use this annotation, the compiler will generate both a static method in the enclosing class of the object and an instance method in the object itself`

Comment: what if @JvmStatic is not used?

Comment: @RabindraKhadka A method with `@JvmStatic` in the companion object can be called as `ClassName.methodName()` in Java, whereas a method without `@JvmStatic` in the companion object must be called as `ClassName.Companion.methodName()` in Java. There is no difference if you only use Kotlin, no Java at all. For member fields (variables), the same applies annotated with `@JvmField`.

Comment: @Naetmul I don't believe `@JvmField` is related. That's to instruct kotlin not to generate getters/setters. `@JvmStatic` can still be used for fields to make them truly static. Additionally, I believe Companions without annotations behave as a singleton, which isn't the same as a truly static function, even if it just looks like a syntax change.

Answer (score 1):

You can put one or more than one methods and variables inside **campanion object ** Let see example below

```
class DialogClass {
    companion object {
        fun DialogMethod(context: Context) {
            val dialog = Dialog(context)
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            dialog.show()
        }
        fun AnotherMethod() {
            // Implement own logic here.
        }
    }
}
```